# AWS Serverless Image Handler with image URL signature feature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, thumbor

I am trying to implement AWS Serverless Image Handler (v6.1) using the [Implementation Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/welcome.html).

My images should only be available to authenticated users so I am trying to implement URL signing which is a feature of Serverless Image Handler. I have set up a secret in Secrets Manager and worked out how to create the required signature.

The documentation ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/considerations.html), under the Image URL Signature section) says that I can access my images stored in S3 using the following:

```
https://<distributionName>.cloudfront.net/<YOUR_PATH>?signature=<YOUR_SIGNATURE>
```

This works beautifully and I can see my images in my app.

However (and here's the kicker), the whole point of using Serverless Image Handler in the first place is to optimise images (eg. create thumbnails on the fly from high resolution images stored in the bucket). I cannot for the life of me work out how to implement the various transformations and optimisations that I know are available (and are the whole point of!) Serverless Image Handler **when using the URL signing**. I just can't see how I can send the signature and the transformation/edits/optimisations that I want in the URL.

Does anyone, please, know how to use the [Thumbor filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/thumbor-filters.html) or use any of the image optimisations available in Serverless Image Handler when using URL signing?

Please help!

Surely it should be:

```
https://<distributionName>.cloudfront.net/<THUMBORFILTERCODE>/<YOUR_PATH>?signature=<YOUR_SIGNATURE>
```

...but nope. This doesn't work. It just returns a 403 error.

Comment: Not knowing anything, but did you sign the url with the Thumborfiltercode?

Comment: @mellerbeck NO I WASN'T!!!! Thank you so much. I was just signing the image path and not including the filter. Problem solved. You're a legend.

Comment: cloudfront signing gives me hives :)

Comment: @andrewlaycock do you know how can I use filter autojpg in my edits?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to sign the Thumbor filter along with the image path. Thank you @mellerbeck